# Tooltipster show after 3 seconds delay on second hover

Tags: jquery, callback, hover, tooltip, tooltipster

> I want to show `tooltipster tooltip` after some delay on second time hover

Somehow, I managed to disabled `tooltip` on second hover. But I want to show tooltip on second hover but after some delay.

[**find fiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/1fz99jc5/3/)

This is the code:

```
$('.tooltip').each(function(){
    var pos = $(this).attr('data-position');
    //var hvr = $(this).hover();

    $(this).tooltipster({
        contentAsHTML: true,
        maxWidth: 200,
        position: 'right', 
        speed: 150,
        arrow:false,
        multiple: true,
        positionTracker:true,
        onlyOne: true,
        trigger:'hover',
        offsetX:-25,
        offsetY:-80,
        //theme: '.onlyforcategory',
    });

});

$('.tooltip').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).tooltipster('disable');
});

$('.tooltip').hover(function(){
    //setTimeout(function(){ $(this).tooltipster('enable');}, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply tooltipster on mouseover event on tooltip class elements which are not tooltipstered yet and open it. Tooltip will open immedatly.

In tooltipster setting define **trigger: 'hover'** and **delay: 3000**. tooltipster will open tooltipe with 3s delay on hover event after that (from second hover).

```
  var tooltipInstance;
        $("body").on('mouseover', '.tooltip:not(.tooltipstered)', function(){
            var pos = $(this).attr('data-position');
            //var hvr = $(this).hover();
            tooltipInstance = $(this).tooltipster({
                trigger: 'hover',
                delay: 3000,
                contentAsHTML: true,
                maxWidth: 200,
                position: 'right',
                speed: 150,
                arrow:false,
                multiple: true,
                positionTracker:true,
                onlyOne: true,
                trigger:'hover',
                offsetX:-25,
                offsetY:-80,
                //theme: '.onlyforcategory',
            });
            tooltipInstance.tooltipster('open');
         });
```